# how to replace src img when clicking (html/css or JS)

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

I have a menu with images like icons, when I click on one of them it will show something different, and I'd like to change the image when it's 'active', turn it into red and back in grey when I click on the next one, I'm sure if I'm clear. I've tried a lot of thing but nothing actually works.

How it looks right now
[image: How it looks right now]

how it's supposed to look
[image: how it's supposed to look like]

and when I click on the next one
[image: and when I click on the next one]

so here's my actual code, its 100% html/css but i can also use JS

thank you

```
<div class="filter-foodmenu-tab">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#foodmenu1" role="tab"><span>
          <img src="menu/cat-midi_grey.png" width="40px" class="foodmenu1" id ="img1" onclick="changeImage()"></span><br/><br/>
          formule midi</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#foodmenu2" role="tab"><span>
          <img src="menu/cat-entree_grey.png" width="40px" class="foodmenu2" id ="img2"></span><br/><br/>  
          entrées</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#foodmenu3" role="tab"><span>
          <img src="menu/cat-piadina_grey.png" width="40px" class="foodmenu3" id="img3" ></span><br/><br/> 
          piadinas</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="active" data-toggle="tab" href="#foodmenu3-1" role="tab"><span>
          <img src="menu/cat-piadina_grey-1.png" width="40px" class="foodmenu3-1" id="img4"></span><br/><br/> 
          la pinsa</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#foodmenu4" role="tab"><span>
          <img src="menu/cat-pates_grey.png" width="40px" class="foodmenu4" id="img5"></span><br/><br/>
          pâtes</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#foodmenu5" role="tab"><span>
          <img src="menu/cat-dessert_grey.png" width="40px" class="foodmenu5" id="img6"></span><br/><br/> 
          desserts</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#foodmenu6" role="tab"><span>
          <img src="menu/cat-bambino_grey.png" width="70px" class="foodmenu6" id="img7"></span><br/>
          menu bambino</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Here's the thing. You need a proper script. What should happen when the user clicks a second image? You want the first to revert, right? What other content should change when you click? There's more to this than just the image source. I suggest a tutorial in basic JavaScript, and then come back with a more specific question. Basic source switching is well documented already.

Comment: Community moderators: the problem with this question isn't a matter of duplicates. It's a matter of focus. The proposed duplicate is insufficient.

Comment: You need to post complete code on what you've tried. You only have html code, without about your css and javascript?

Comment: Best option is to use svg and change colors using js or css. If not possible, then load both red & gray images and hide one depending on active status. This is better since changing src might bring a delay in which new source is fetched.

Comment: It looks like you're using Bootstrap, and it provides an active class which you can style; you need to be running the Bootstrap js first, though.

Comment: You can use jquery selector which is exact matches css select

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple JS function for that.
First of all, add the `onclick="changeImage(this);"` to every img tag you want to handle it's click event.
Then, add this html tag to contain the JS code:

```html
<script>
var prevImage = undefined;

function changeImage(imgElement) {
    if(prevImage) {
        prevImage.src = prevImage.src.replace('red', 'grey');
    }

    imgElement.src = imgElement.src.replace('grey', 'red');
    prevImage = imgElement;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the requirement that the original image be reverted upon clicking another.